# NoMethodError at / undefined method `call' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I get this error when loading a ror site i am responsible for. The strange thing is its deployed from a war file that hasnt changed since the last deploy. It happens randomly every so often when i restart tomcat. Backtrace is as follows;

```
file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/gems-gems-jruby-rack-1.1.16-lib-jruby-rack-1.1.16.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb in call

line22: self.class.response.new(@app.call(create_env(servlet_env)))
```

I'm assuming this is a problem with a gem file. Why would this be happening given other sites using the same setup dont have this problem? What can i do to stop this occuring?

Comment: That's not much to go on. You'll have to give more context.

Comment: Whatever object `@app` is doesn't have a call method.  What is `@app`?

Comment: @tadman Apologies for the lack of context. I assumed it was relating to the gem and thought it may have been a problem experienced before. What further information would be helpful.

Comment: A full stack trace, if applicable? Any error messages from the log? **Anything**, really.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be a poor deployment as when i redepoyed the application it worked this time. No understanding of why though.